# Oracle's materialized view: How to determine whether original tables were changed?

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I've created a MV, on many tables. I don't want to auto-refresh it. I just want to know whether original tables were changed or not. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created fast refresh MVs, you also created Materialied View logs on base tables.
You can Issue an `select count(*)` from corresponding MV log(is a table that contains the table name and an M_$ or something like).

But If you want just to know if a refresh is needed, you can safely shoot a fast refresh. It would be at light speed if there are no rows to refresh.

Comment: So there is no oracle view that contains info whether MV is actual or not?

Comment: only fast refresh MVs keep this sort of information. You can check the materialized view logs, as I said

Comment: How about that: "SELECT STALENESS FROM user_mviews WHERE mview_name = ...", is that good solution?

Comment: seems you are right http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1105.htm#i1582466 Yes, I think this flag is trustworthy, you can test it.